# Send data to specific sockets in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have this code at the nodejs:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    clients.push(socket);   

    function broadcast(message) {
        clients.forEach(function (client) {
            client.write(message);
        });
    }

    broadcast("Hey");
}
```

How do I make this function send data to specific clients without "FOR (i++)"
I need fastest solution. Because there will be over 1 000 ++ concurent connections.

For example:

```
ID 1 -> room 1
ID 2 -> room 1
ID 3 -> room 2
```

So ID 1 and ID 2 will share the data and ID will not even know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the way you're doing it is best, but if you want to go balls to the wall you could check out http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got you right but if you need to send a kind of message or event to some specific clients

Then you don't have to loop through these clients, if they are specific. 
Nodejs socketio provides chat room for this purpose 
you should make those specific clients joined a specific room and later on just send the message to all those who are joined the room 
I provided a small piece of code as an example for you

```
    socket.join("roomName");
    socket.broadcast.to("roomName").emit( 'message' ,'body of message');
    io.sockets.in("roomName").emit('message','body of next message');
```

I have to add that it's very easy to use even the roomName doesn't exist it will be created by the first line command

Comment: the thing is that I can not use socket.io, I am using net.

Comment: though your answer does make sence.